# Cakephp vs Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cakephp

I'm a Cakephp developer but my colleagues say that it is slow compared to Codeigniter and I must say that there shouldn't be too much of a difference since you can use cache to speed things up.

Is the speed that noticeable with Cakephp and Codeigniter and is it a significant issue over selecting CI over Cake or should I not bother too much about this?

Comment: Your question is way too broad.

Comment: You shouldn't bother too much about it.

Comment: yii framework speed is said to be higher even!

Comment: Good answer to this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548923/cakephp-vs-codeigniter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Speed, does not suppose to be the key in your decision of your framework.

number of features that are built in with the framework should be one of your first priorities.
 **this is for example some thing that will help you speed up things and not develop from scratch**

Community size and development life cycle of the FW are also important.

You should always remember that choosing a framework is very subjective and depend on your needs.

So my opinion here that there is not one sharp answer, it is always about trade off's in life.